# django-filters and HTMX: Trigger a Filter on Multiple Views at Once

Tags: django, django-filter, htmx

I have a simple app where I want to have a single filter dynamically update the queryset in two different Views at the same time.

In this example, the user can filter based on city/country/continent and I'd like to dynamically update (1) the table showing the relevant objects in the model, and (2) the leaflet map to plot the points.

---

I think the main issue here is that I need to trigger an update to the filter queryset on multiple 'views' at the same time and not sure how to structure my project to achieve that. Or if that's the right way to think about the problem.

I'm trying to have a filter work with`{% for city in cityFilterResults %}` iterator in two different views at the same time.

How can I achieve having two different views update based on a Filter using HTMX?

---

**`index.html`:**

(Note: My expected behaviour works if I switch the `hx-get` URL between either the table or the map. But they don't filter together and this is the issue I'm stuck on.)

```
<body>

<h3>Filter Controls:</h3><br>
<form hx-get="{% url '_city_table' %}" hx-target="#cityTable">   
<!-- <form hx-get="{% url '_leaflet' %}" hx-target="#markers">    -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ cityFilterForm.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Filter </button>
</form>

[...]

<!-- Table Body -->
<tbody id="cityTable" hx-get="{% url '_city_table' %}" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="nearest tr"> </tbody>

[...]

<!-- Div to get the markers -->
<div id="markers" hx-get="{% url '_leaflet' %}" hx-trigger="my_custom_trigger from:body"> </div>

</body>
<script>
[... Leaflet stuff ...]
document.getElementById('markers');
</script>
```

**`_city_table.html`:**

```
{% for city in cityFilterResults %}

<tr>
    <td> {{ city.city }} </td>
    <td> {{ city.country }} </td>
    <td> {{ city.continent }} </td>
    <td> {{ city.latitude|floatformat:4 }} </td>
    <td> {{ city.longitude|floatformat:4  }} </td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

**`_leaflet.html`:**

```
<script>

if (map.hasLayer(group)) {
    console.log('LayerGroup already exists');
    group.clearLayers();
    map.removeLayer(group);
} else {
    console.log('LayerGroup doesn't exist');
}


{% for city in cityFilterResults %}
    var marker = L.marker([{{city.latitude}}, {{city.longitude}}]).addTo(group)
    .bindPopup("{{city.city}}")
{% endfor %}

group.addTo(map);
</script>
```

**`views.py`**:

```
def _city_table(request):

    city_filter_form = cityFilter(request.GET, queryset=cityModel.objects.all())
    city_filter_results = city_filter_form.qs

    context={   'cityModel': cityModel.objects.all(),
                'cityFilterResults': city_filter_results }
    
    response = render(request, '_city_table.html', context)
    response['HX-Trigger'] = 'my_custom_trigger'
    return response

def _leaflet(request):

    city_filter_form = cityFilter(request.GET, queryset=cityModel.objects.all())
    city_filter_results = city_filter_form.qs

    context={   'cityModel': cityModel.objects.all(),
                'cityFilterResults': city_filter_results }
    return render(request, '_leaflet.html', context)
```

---

When the `hx-get` on Filter form points to the URL for `_city_table` template, then the table filters as expected but the map does not:

[image]

When the `hx-get` on Filter form points to the URL for the `_leaflet` template, then the map filters but the table does not:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find some solution here:
https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/

In particular ther are two solutions

**swap-oob** (
https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/#oob )

You have to post your form to the action of your controller.
The action return the two element that will be  replaced

```
<button hx-get="/Form/OutOfBandResponse" hx-swap="none">ok</button>

<div id="A"></div>

<div id="B"></div>
```

This is the response:

```
<!-- this will replace the element with id A -->
<div id="A" hx-swap-oob="true">
    Joe Smith
</div>

<!-- this will replace the element with id B -->    
<div id="B" hx-swap-oob="true">
    Antony Queen
</div>
```

**In alternative you can use events.** ( https://htmx.org/examples/update-other-content/#events )

So you have to create a handler for a event, then when you submit the form you have to response with a header that fire that event.
When the event fire, the divs react updating their self.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I was using the 'event' approach already in my answer. I checked into the OOB and watched a video and also looks like it would solve my usecase. Thanks, Marco.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing a solution to my question. It works, which is awesome, but I would very much like to understand what alternative approaches could be implemented. My approach feels like a hack and think I'm missing something.

---

I was able to use a `session` to pass the filter between the views. Basically, I am using the Filter form on the table. In the 'views' for the table, two things are happening: (1) I create a `session` and store the filter results, and (2) return a HTTP response with a header that serves as a trigger for the HTMX on the Leaflet part.

In the HTML template, I have the Leaflet URL waiting for the custom HTMX trigger to come back with the table. Then, in the Leaflet views, I take the data from the `session`.

---

**`views.py`:**

```
def _city_table(request):

    city_filter_form = cityFilter(request.GET, queryset=cityModel.objects.all())
    city_filter_results = city_filter_form.qs


    request.session['my_city_filter'] = [city.id for city in city_filter_results] 
    request.session.modified=True


    context={   'cityModel': cityModel.objects.all(),
                'cityFilterResults': city_filter_results }
    
    response = render(request, '_city_table.html', context)
    response['HX-Trigger'] = 'my_custom_trigger'
    return response

def _leaflet(request):

    city_filter_results = [cityModel.objects.get(id=id) for id in request.session['my_city_filter']]

    context={   'cityModel': cityModel.objects.all(),
                'cityFilterResults': city_filter_results }
    return render(request, '_leaflet.html', context)
```

**`index.html`:**

```
<div id="markers" hx-get="{% url '_leaflet' %}" hx-trigger="my_custom_trigger from:body"> </div>
```